# Nginx sever block not function as expected

Tags: nginx

I'm using this config file with nginx:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name harrybilney.co.uk;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name kyra-mcd.co.uk;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
}
```

Which is stored in `/etc/nginx/sites-avaliable`. The server block for the domain `kyra-mcd.co.uk` works perfectly as expected but the server block for `harrybilney.co.uk` does not and my browser cannot find the server for `harrybilney.co.uk`.

Both domains are hosted with GoDaddy and have the exact same DNS settings pointing towards my static IP (IPv4 and IPv6 with A and AAAA records).

Can anyone explain why I'm having this issue as I've tried changing the config but getting luck. I understand this is a very basic config file for nginx but for now I'm just trying to get both domains working on my 1 static IP before I add in anything complex.

Comment: @BijayRegmi this is just wrong! nothing will be overwriten here. NGINX will read all config files on startup and hold a single configuration object if you want to name in menory. So there is no reason to have a seperate file!

Comment: Whats the output of `sudo nginx -T`. So instead of `proxy_pass` you can use `return 200 "$host\n;"` Then use `curl` to test. `curl -v http://kyra-mcd.co.uk` whould print out `kyra-mcd.co.uk`.

Comment: This may be a DNS propogation, I tested and both of them work fine on curl

Answer (score 0):

Having both `server` blocks in a single file IS NO PROBLEM!

Here is a default.conf file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name harrybilney.co.uk;

  location / {
    return 200 "$host\n";
  }
}


server {
  listen 80;
  server_name kyra-mcd.co.uk;

  location / {
    return 200 "Host should match kyra-mcd.co.uk = $host\n";
  }

}
```

Test and reload your config by issuing `sudo nginx -t && sudo nginx -s reload`

The curl test:

```
$# curl -H "Host: kyra-mcd.co.uk" localhost
Host should match kyra-mcd.co.uk = kyra-mcd.co.uk
```

```
$# curl -H "Host: harrybilney.co.uk" localhost
harrybilney.co.uk
```

As you can see both servers are in a single file and the `server_name` taking care of finding the correct server-block based on the `Host` header.

Check your DNS one more time. Worh it:

```
kyra-mcd.co.uk.     600 IN  A   90.255.228.109
harrybilney.co.uk.  3600    IN  A   90.255.228.109
```

Looks good to me as well. So the traffic should hit the server.

So your configuration looks good for me. Make sure everything is loaded by issuing `sudo nginx -T`.

`curl` is working on my end. So looks like the problem is related to DNS on your end. Can you confirm `curl` is working from your end as well?